# connecting java to Mysql using Mysql-connector/j

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I use netbeans 6.9 IDE and its features to connect my java class to Mysql database.
as you know, Mysql-connector driver is embedded in netbeans. I make new connection to Mysql database using Mysql(connector/j) driver, and every thing is okay, it displays all databases in Mysql and all tables in these databases, but when I create my java class to test the connetion and start manipulation, ClassNotFoundException is thrown when I call `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` 
ie. there is no driver ? why i got that exception ? the same happened when I connect to derby embedded db? can you help?
here my test class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("driver true");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///test",
                    "root", "123456");
            if (!con.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully connected to "
                        + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the `mysql` connector .jar file (Libraries + Add Library + Mysql JDBC Driver) to your project.

Answer (score 1):

On the left side Right-Click "**libraries**"->"**Add Library...**"-Select->"**MySQL JDBC Driver**"   then rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is with your question. Driver is with your netbeans IDE and not with your java project. Add the required dirver (Jar file) to the project and run.